# How to sum of some numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve the linear equation (please expalin it step by step)?
The linear equation is:
$$
\frac 12\left(x-\frac 16\right)+\frac 23=\frac 56 +\frac 13 \left(\frac 12-3x\right) 
$$

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that you mean $$\frac12\left(x-\frac16\right)+\frac23=\frac56+\frac13\left(\frac12-3x\right),$$ you'll begin by distributing. Simplify both sides. Isolate the variable.

---

Let me work a similar problem with different numbers to show you the idea. Let's begin with $$\frac14\left(2x-\frac12\right)+\frac38=\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac12-9x\right).$$

In order to solve the equation, we'll need to get $x$ by itself on one side of the equation. Right now, though, we have an $x$ on both sides of the equation, trapped as it were within parentheses, so we can't bring them together to isolate $x$. To eliminate this problem, we will distribute--that is, use the fact that $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ and $a(b-c)=ab-ac.$ This lets us rewrite the equation as $$\frac14\cdot2x-\frac14\cdot\frac12+\frac38=\frac54+\frac13\cdot\frac12-\frac13\cdot9x.$$ Now our $x$s are no longer stuck inside parentheses, but we have a serious mess on our hands. Let's simplify both sides by taking care of those multiplications: $$\frac14\cdot\frac21x-\frac14\cdot\frac12+\frac38=\frac54+\frac13\cdot\frac12-\frac13\cdot\frac91x\\\frac{1\cdot2}{4\cdot1}x-\frac{1\cdot1}{4\cdot2}+\frac38=\frac54+\frac{1\cdot1}{3\cdot2}-\frac{1\cdot9}{3\cdot1}x\\\frac24x-\frac18+\frac38=\frac54+\frac16-\frac93x$$ Better, but not great. Let's simplify the fractions that we can. $$\frac12x-\frac18+\frac38=\frac54+\frac16-3x$$ Now, let's go ahead and combine the floating fractions on each side by rewriting (if necessary) with a common denominator, adding/subtracting, and then simplifying $$\frac12x-\frac18+\frac38=\frac{15}{12}+\frac2{12}-3x\\\frac12x+\frac{-1+3}8=\frac{15+2}{12}-3x\\\frac12x+\frac28=\frac{17}{12}-3x\\\frac12x+\frac14=\frac{17}{12}-3x$$ At this point, note that since both sides of the equation are different ways of representing *the same number*, then we can add or subtract the same thing on both sides of the equation and *still* have an equation. In particular, we'd really like to get all our $x$ terms on one side, and the rest of the terms on the other. Well, in order to undo a subtraction of $3x,$ we have to add $3x$. Doing this on both sides: $$\frac12x+\frac14+3x=\frac{17}{12}-3x+3x\\3x+\frac12x+\frac14=\frac{17}{12}+0\\3x+\frac12x+\frac14=\frac{17}{12}$$ We're getting closer, now, but we really want just $x$ terms on the left, so to undo addition by $\frac14,$ we subtract $\frac14$ from both sides: $$3x+\frac12x+\frac14-\frac14=\frac{17}{12}-\frac14\\3x+\frac12x+0=\frac{17}{12}-\frac14\\3x+\frac12x=\frac{17}{12}-\frac14$$ We can make the right-hand side simpler by rewriting with common denominator, subtracting, and simplifying: $$3x+\frac12x=\frac{17}{12}-\frac3{12}\\3x+\frac12x=\frac{17-3}{12}\\3x+\frac12x=\frac{14}{12}\\3x+\frac12x=\frac76$$ Now, we notice that there is a common factor of $x$ on the left-hand side, so we "undistribute": $$\left(3+\frac12\right)x=\frac76$$ We can make this simpler by once again rewriting with a common denominator and adding: $$\left(\frac31+\frac12\right)x=\frac76\\\left(\frac62+\frac12\right)x=\frac76\\\frac{6+1}2x=\frac76\\\frac72x=\frac76$$ Our final step is to get rid of that multiple of $\frac72.$ Remember that both sides of the equation are different ways to represent the *same number*, so if we multiply by the same thing on both sides, we'll *still* have an equation. In particular, multiplying by $\frac27$ on both sides and simplifying gets us: $$\frac27\cdot\frac72x=\frac27\cdot\frac76\\\frac{2\cdot 7}{7\cdot 2}x=\frac{2\cdot 7}{7\cdot 6}\\\frac{14}{14}x=\frac{14}{42}\\1\cdot x=\frac13\\\boxed{x=\frac13}$$ We really should check that carefully, though, to be sure we didn't make any mistakes. So, we substitute $x=\frac13$ back into the original equation, and see that $$\frac14\left(2\cdot\frac13-\frac12\right)+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac12-9\cdot\frac13\right)\\\frac14\left(\frac21\cdot\frac13-\frac12\right)+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac12-\frac91\cdot\frac13\right)\\\frac14\left(\frac{2\cdot1}{1\cdot3}-\frac12\right)+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac12-\frac{9\cdot1}{1\cdot3}\right)\\\frac14\left(\frac23-\frac12\right)+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac12-\frac93\right)\\\frac14\left(\frac46-\frac36\right)+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\left(\frac36-\frac{18}6\right)\\\frac14\cdot\frac{4-3}6+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\cdot\frac{3-18}6\\\frac14\cdot\frac16+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac13\cdot\frac{-15}6\\\frac{1\cdot1}{4\cdot6}+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac{1\cdot-15}{3\cdot6}\\\frac1{24}+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac{-15}{18}\\\frac1{24}+\frac38\overset{?}{=}\frac54+\frac{-5}6\\\frac1{24}+\frac9{24}\overset{?}{=}\frac{15}{12}+\frac{-10}{12}\\\frac{1+9}{24}\overset{?}{=}\frac{15+-10}{12}\\\frac{10}{24}\overset{?}{=}\frac5{12}\\\frac5{12}\overset{?}{=}\frac5{12}$$ Hence, our answer was correct! A similar approach can be taken to your problem. I arguably showed more steps than strictly necessary, here, but I wanted it to be clear what I was doing. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: can you please solve it (with procedure showing me step by step)

Comment: I can, yes, but that would not be very helpful. How many of the steps I suggested were you able to do?

Comment: +1 for not showing the solution to the question asked, but rather a nearly equivalent problem.  I think I'll try doing this when I see problems where that would apply. :)

Comment: @anorton: Glad you liked it! I prefer hints when possible (full solutions can be pretty time-consuming), but sometimes similar problems are definitely the way to go when comprehension/confidence is low.

Answer (score 0):

1) distribute the fraction that is multiplied to the polynomial in the parenthesis

```
a(c+d) = ac + ad
```

2) move all terms with "x" on one side of the equal sign

```
2x + 5 = x +7 becomes 2x - x = 7 - 5
```

3) combine like terms

4) solve for x

Comment: Yes, the valus of X to be solved. But how can u pls explain me (step by step) now to understanding me. Thanks